# Python revise global variables inside function

Tags: python, global-variables, exec

### Background

Suppose I have 2 global variables `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = ['a','b']`, If I must exchange `a` and `b` inside a function, I can do with following code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b']
def fun1():
    global a,b
    temp = a[::-1]
    a = b[::-1]
    b = temp
fun1()
print(a,b)
```

Out:

> ['b', 'a'] [3, 2, 1]

However, If `a` and `b` are parameters of my function, how do we do it?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b']
def fun2(a,b):
    global a,b
    temp = a[::-1]
    a = b[::-1]
    b = temp
fun2(a,b)
print(a,b)
```

Raise Error:

> SyntaxError: name 'a' is parameter and global

### My attempt

**I tried to do with `exec`, it works on Python 3.7, However, it does not work on Codewars 3.6 env.** I don't know the reason, maybe I just find wrong method.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b']
def exchange_with(a, b):
    temp = a[::-1].copy()
    exec('a = b[::-1]',globals())
    exec('b = temp',locals(),globals())
exchange_with(a, b)
a,b
```

Out:

> (['b', 'a'], [3, 2, 1])

Comment: func2(a,b) require 2 args but you don't give any

Comment: @ErnestBidouille sry for that , I revised

Comment: You can't have a variable as an parameter and  global you have to choose. It's better not to use global, just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to pass the values as arguments. Once inside the function, you need to make in-place slice assignments to each list. No global names need be involved.

```
def fun2(a,b):
    a[:], b[:] = b[::-1], a[::-1]

x = [1,2,3]
y = ['a', 'b']
fun2(x, y)
assert x == ['b', 'a']
assert y == [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I used to treat `a` and `b` inside function body as local variable, which means `a` inside function body only contains value of global `a`. However, your method is absolutely right!  `id` of global `a`  `==`  `id(a)` inside function. I think it is so dangerous that we can revise global variable `a` without a `global a` statement. So in practice, better to not change global variables like this?

Comment: `a` and `b` *are* local variables, but that doesn't mean they can't refer to values that are also referred to by global variables, which means that if you aren't careful, you can mutate global state using a local variables. (If you haven't already, you may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.) In other words, *names* have scope, but values do not.

Comment: @chepner Not OP but thanks for your reply. However, the link you posted doesn't work, care to give it an update? I followed here from your CodeWars answer. My question is: why `[:]` will make it work when the function is `a, b = b[::-1], a[::-1]`, the global values don't get changed at all? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the link should be https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html; the end-of-sentence period got included.

Comment: `a = ...` is an ordinary assignment; it makes the name `a` refer to a new value regardless of what it used to refer to. `a[:] = ...` isn't "really" an assignment at all; it's implemented by a method call `a.__setitem__(slice(None, None, None), ...)`.

Comment: @chepner Now I understand it. Thanks. Sort of like the pandas `.loc` selecting and setting values for dataframe?

Comment: I think so, not being terribly familiar with pandas myself.